# User input cardinal point "Orientation"

Tags: input-fields, research

I create a website for Solar Power.

The user can choose the `position` `orientation` and `inclination` of his solar power plant and then receive an estimate of the possible energy production.

Do you know any examples for user inputs for `orientation` and `inclination`? I don't want to just add boring dropdowns or radio buttons with `N, E, S, W` and `10°, 20° …`

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using images displaying what orientation and inclination means, and the ability to modify the values using sliders.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSyBhO.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Since the situation of the panels is likely to be geo sensitive I would suggest using the Google maps API.

The user would be able to select the geographic location of the panel by the normal Google Maps search (long/lat, zip, etc.).

Once the user has determined the geographic location they would be 'offered' the optimum orientation and inclination for their location shown as a line on the map (orientation) and an angular value (inclination).

To edit the orientation the user could drag the line by the middle to relocate or by either end to rotate and enter a new value for inclination.

Although it's also advisable to include a more familiar orientation input.

Something like this:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feLEjU.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: Great idea. Unfortunately a bit too complex to implement for such a small usecase. But I'll keep that in mind.